# C++ experimental filesystem library incomplete?

Tags: c++, g++, filesystems, ubuntu-18.04

I found a neat method inside the `<experimental/filesystem>` include which tells my if a path is a file or directory but it gives me an error when trying to use it on g++ v 7.4.0. The method I am trying to use is: `.is_regular_file()`.

It's even on cppref, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/is_regular_file.

But when compiling i get "...has no member named 'is_regular_file'" error. I can't use the regular filesystem because my target system (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) has g++ 7.4.0 preinstalled and can't be changed.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Does anyone know an alternative to is_regular_file for me so i can check if a file is a dir or file?

My includes are:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <experimental/filesystem>
```

And I am using the following flags: -std=c++17 -lstdc++fs -O3 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror

Comment: Can you try the first overload from cppref? Or have you checked all three overloads and none are existing/working?

Comment: Please provide a full [repro] for the issue. The function is present in the GCC 7.4.0 header file: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/releases/gcc-7.4.0/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/experimental/bits/fs_ops.h#L214

Comment: Tried all three, when writing the dot after my variable it's not even suggesting anything except: `path`, `status`, `symlink_status` and `~directory_entry` as well as every overloaded operator. @ezegoing

Comment: @MaxPower What dot? This is a free function in the `std::experimental::filesystem` namespace. I think you mistook it for a member function.

Comment: "experimental" means: it's potluck. It may work. Or it may not work. Or it may reformat your hard drive. Use at your own risk. That's the very definition of "experimental".

Comment: Well now I feel silly, It was a free function.. strangely I recall it working like a member function in my g++v9 environment. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik you seem to be confusing "experimental" and "undefined behaviour". There is no way that any of GCC's "experimental" TS implementations should format your hard drive. The problem here is that the library implements the TS specification and the code is trying to use the C++17 specification. That's nothing to do with the quality of the "experimental" library or its likelihood to work, or format your hard drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confused, because `std::experimental::filesystem` (`<experimental/filesystem>`) contains the Filesystem TS, not the filesystem additions to C++17 which are found in `std::filesystem` (`<filesystem>`) if your standard library implements them (although the latter is based on the former).

In the TS there is a [`std::experimental::filesystem::is_regular_file`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/is_regular_file) free function (which you link to in the question). This free [`std::filesystem::is_regular_file`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/is_regular_file) also exists in C++17.

However in C++17 the [`std::filesystem::directory_entry`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_entry) class also has a member function [`is_regular_file`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_entry/is_regular_file).

This member function is absent in the TS version [`std::experimental::filesystem::directory_entry`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/directory_entry).

The TS is not exactly the same as what was then later added to the standard library for C++17.

Comment: I see! I didn't know they did the later implementation a little bit different than the experimental version. Thanks for the more detailed explanation!

Comment: In addition to the informative answer, this is what works on both implementations: `fs::is_regular_file(myEntry.status())`